# Calling a recursive method from another class that reverses a linked list

Tags: java, recursion

I have currently have 2 classes, Images and ImageNode. Inside the ImageNode class I have a recursive method that reverses the linked list. I believe my code is correct for that method, however i'm confused as to how I should be calling this method inside my Images class.

ImageNode method ---

```
 public ImageNode reverseUsingPrevious(ImageNode previous) {
    if(previous == null) return previous;

    ImageNode next = previous.getNext();

    if(next == null) return previous;

    previous.setNext(null);
    ImageNode rev = reverseUsingPrevious(next);
    next.setNext(previous);
    return rev;
}
```

Images method ----

```
private void reverseRec() {
    cursor.reverseUsingPrevious(head);
//the cursor is the currently selected image(node), head is the start of the linked list
}
```

I'm not 100% sure what I should be parsing into reverseUsingPrevious method.

Comment: "I believe my code is correct" So what is your question? What does *not* work?

Comment: I believe my reverseUsingPrevious is correct but not my reverseRec() method... that method is causing the problem

Comment: Please specify: is it a double linked list? Please post the ImageNode's class attributes. Did your task explicitly demand a recursive methods as solution?

Comment: You need to put a lot more info in this question. I'd suggest you remove all the stuff about images and nodes etc.. and think about what, fundametally, you are having problems with and ask that question. I wont vote you down since you are new, but you are asking for it.

Comment: My apologies, I will re-evaluate my problem and try explain it a bit better. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the head by adding `head =` before the `cursor.reverseUsingPrevious(head);`.

Extra tip:

Even though the method `reverseUsingPrevious` probably works as it is, it doesn't call any methods or variables on the local object at all (apart from the call to `reverseUsingPrevious`), so it could just as well have been static.

But rather than making it static, you could drop the parameter `(ImageNode previous)`, and replace every instance of `previous` with `this`.

Now, instead of calling `reverseUsingPrevious(node)`, you put the node in front instead: `node.reverseUsingPrevious()`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was close, thanks for understanding what I was trying to get across. I do believe it could be better but It does the job I need it to do... Thanks for the tip, will keep that in mind.